# SQL (postgreSQL) create table of points from condition

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am new to SQL and appreciate any advice.

I am trying to put a conditional where statement into my query to filter the point generation to just where column 2 has 01.

```
CREATE TABLE schema.table2 AS
    
SELECT "column1", "column2", dp.geom 
    
FROM table1 WHERE column2 = "01", st_dumppoints(st_generatepoints(schema.geom, CAST(schema.column1 AS INT))) AS dp;
```

The query works fine when I take out 'WHERE column2 = "01"'

Comment: What you are trying to do after your comma.. `where column2 = "01", st_dumppoints...`.  And strings should be enclosed with single quotes, not double.

Comment: Changed to single thank you! Creating random points within a polygon

Comment: Never ever use double quotes " in your SQL code. If you need them, you made a mistake. Fix that mistake, using just lower case names for all objects, and you don't need the double quotes anymore.

Comment: In postgresql all identifiers are in lower case. You can write column1, cOlUmn1, or COLUMN1 in you query, but postgresql will convert it to lower case when parsing the query. Unless you quote them with double quotes. Then it will keep it as you wrote it. And you will  have to quote it every time you use it. ***DO NOT DO THAT!***, please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`ST_GeneratePoints()`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_GeneratePoints.html) is a scalar function, so you can plug it right into the [set-returning](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-table-expressions.html#QUERIES-TABLEFUNCTIONS) [`ST_DumpPoints()`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_DumpPoints.html), right in the `select` list. [Demo at db<>fiddle:](https://dbfiddle.uk/QznBslO9)

```
CREATE TABLE schema.table2 AS
SELECT column1, 
       column2,
       (st_dumppoints(st_generatepoints(geom, column1::int)) ).geom
FROM table1
WHERE column2 = '01';

select column1, column2, st_astext(geom) from schema.table2;
```

| column1 | column2 | st_astext |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 01 | POINT(5.86390304259572 1.927184679457311) |
| 2 | 01 | POINT(3.212729817760193 7.706451275408435) |
| 3 | 01 | POINT(16.515447825106357 22.141316310508124) |
| 3 | 01 | POINT(25.303230663190877 25.957851538628983) |
| 3 | 01 | POINT(13.569699797511326 18.562723639342707) |

If you want to stick to your current layout, you'll need to move the `WHERE` list to go *after* the `FROM` list - the syntax error you were probably getting was because you placed the condition right in the middle of it.

It's also advisable to be very careful with [`,` commas](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/tutorial-join.html#TUTORIAL-JOIN) resulting in implicit joins. Consider using [`CROSS JOIN LATERAL`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-table-expressions.html#QUERIES-JOIN) explicitly instead, since that's what your use of the `,` comma would be translated to:

```sql
CREATE TABLE schema.table3 AS
SELECT column1, column2, dp.geom 
FROM table1 
CROSS JOIN LATERAL st_dumppoints(st_generatepoints(geom,column1::int)) AS dp
WHERE column2 = '01';
```

Mind the quotes:

- `'01'` is a constant `text` value
- `"01"` is a reference to a column or a variable of that name

My bet is you wanted the former, not the latter, and having fixed the `from..where..,` comma issue, you could've gotten an error saying that the column `"01"` wasn't found. [Chapter 4. SQL Syntax, section 4.1. Lexical Structure](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS) covers the topic.

Technically it isn't invalid to name your column `"01"` and then search for rows where the value in `column2` is equal to the value in column `"01"` (shown in [the demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/QznBslO9)), but I don't think that's what you want, and that's not a very clear/practical naming system. You can even name a column `"` (a double quote character) or a   (a single space) but while that's not technically wrong, I'd say morally it's pretty evil.

Comment: It's running! Thank you so much for your explanations! Biggest takeaway from this post is no double quotes hahaha